# Why does fsolve give the initial condition as the solution?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def f_sum(beta, gamma, x):
    f = (
        3 * x ** (3 * (1 - gamma)) / (np.exp(1 / beta) - x ** (1 - gamma))
        + x ** (4 * (1 - gamma)) / (np.exp(1 / beta) - x ** (1 - gamma)) ** 2
        - 3 * x ** (3) / (np.exp(1 / beta) - x ** (1))
        - x ** (4 * (1)) / (np.exp(1 / beta) - x ** (1)) ** 2
    )
    return f


def equilibrium(p, beta, gamma, x):
    if x > 1:
        return 1000
    elif x < -1:
        return -1000
    else:
        g = (
            x * (1 - x ** 2) * (1 - p) / 2
            + f_sum(beta, gamma, (x + 1) / 2)
            - f_sum(beta, gamma, (1 - x) / 2)
        )
    return g


print(fsolve(lambda x: equilibrium(1.0, 0.1, 0.3775, x), 0.6))
```

I am using fsolve to find the roots of a function strictly between -1 and 1. x is between -1 and 1. And gamma is between 0 and 0.5. Beta is positive.

I know that the function has 3 roots -1, 0 and 1. I just try to see if there are more for specific combination of parameters.

However, for specific parameters, the solution is the same one with the initial condition. I tried to plot the function and there is no such fixed point so that's obviously wrong.

I also get the following error: "RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the
improvement from the last ten iterations.
warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)"

What's the problem? I also tried to change the initial conditions for the chosen parameters (in the print function) but higher than initial=0.6 it keeps giving initial value.

Comment: Hi. You need to deeply study your function. You have two singularities for `x=e**(1/beta*(1-gamma))` and `x=e**(1/beta)`. You need to check the function domain, is it always defined for `x<0`?. I guess what you call "fixed points" are the function roots `f(x)=0`. You can simply verify that for `beta=gamma=1` for `x=0` you get `y!=0` so `0` is not always a root.

Comment: Hi, they are not singularities because x is between -1 and 1. And I should have specified that gamma is between 0 and 0.5, sorry for that, thanks for the note i ll edit it .

Comment: Ah ok. Is this your function? https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/kbdnv97h

Comment: Yes exactly. But I care for small p lets say for now p<1. Using geogebra, I played with the parameters and there are no other roots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the complexity of your `equilibrium` function and its limited domain x∈[-1,1], it's better to use `least_squares`, for example

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def f_sum(x, beta, gamma):
    f = (
        3 * x ** (3 * (1 - gamma)) / (np.exp(1 / beta) - x ** (1 - gamma))
        + x ** (4 * (1 - gamma)) / (np.exp(1 / beta) - x ** (1 - gamma)) ** 2
        - 3 * x ** (3) / (np.exp(1 / beta) - x ** (1))
        - x ** (4 * (1)) / (np.exp(1 / beta) - x ** (1)) ** 2
    )
    return f


def equilibrium(x, p, beta, gamma):
    g = (
        x * (1 - x ** 2) * (1 - p) / 2
        + f_sum((x + 1) / 2, beta, gamma)
        - f_sum((1 - x) / 2, beta, gamma)
    )
    return g
```

Now we can find the roots in the defined domain (`bounds`)

```
roots = least_squares(
    equilibrium, 
    x0=(-1, -.5, 0, .5, 1), 
    args=(2.5, 4.4, 0.06), 
    bounds=(-1, 1)
)
```

that gives

```
print(roots)

 active_mask: array([-1,  0,  0,  0,  1])
        cost: 4.1713539926658053e-22
         fun: array([-1.99740779e-11, -4.23644453e-12,  0.00000000e+00,  4.28902747e-12,
        1.99740779e-11])
        grad: array([ 1.27723833e-10, -1.00057191e-12,  0.00000000e+00,  1.01299110e-12,
       -1.27723833e-10])
         jac: array([[-6.39447955, -0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.23618199,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.        , -0.12019887,  0.        , -0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.        ,  0.        ,  0.236182  , -0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -6.39447955]])
     message: '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
        nfev: 6
        njev: 6
  optimality: 1.358478265237574e-12
      status: 1
     success: True
           x: array([-1.        , -0.34105647,  0.        ,  0.34105647,  1.        ])
```

where the roots are

```
print(roots.x)

[-1.         -0.34105647  0.          0.34105647  1.        ]
```

and we can verify

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)
y = equilibrium(x, 2.5, 4.4, 0.06)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axhline(0, color='r', lw=1)
plt.vlines(roots.x, *plt.ylim(), color='k', ls='--')
```

[image]

## fixed roots

Even if your function `equilibrium` is highly complex, it's relatively easy to prove (without any calculation and/or estimates) that in the domain x∈[-1,1] there are three roots x={-1,0,1} independent from beta and gamma.

In fact, we can write the function grouping similar terms

[image]

Here, for p≠1, necessary condition for f(x)=0 is that A=0 which simply leads to

[image]

So we can now easily show that these conditions are the only roots f(x)=0 and are independent from beta and gamma

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, the three fixed roots are x={-1,0,1}, where f(x)=0 ∀β,γ

Comment: But it s not a necessary condition p!=1, f(x)=0 if A=0. As a counter example in your simulation in geogebra β=0.35, γ=0.14, n=4.5 has 5 roots

Comment: You said you wanted p<1

Comment: Yes but even for p<1 I do not see why it s a necessary condition. The  condition you are saying depends also on γ. If we go a bit above the boundaries for γ and we choose γ=0.87, we get 2 more fixed points.  So for p!=1 *and some conditions for γ that I can't prove* f(x)=0 if A=0. I do not think it is analytical that s why I use fsolve to scan all the combinations. But fsolve does not work. Any ideas why?

Comment: You're right. I was thinking about roots independent from beta and gamma ("fixed roots") but there are two other possible roots dependent on gamma and beta. I'll work on it and on `fsolve`. I'll let you know if I find the issue,

Comment: Perfect, thank you, i did not know about the least square, it works!